# Пересоздание фрагмента

Tags: android

Почему при повороте экрана позиция RecyclerView остается на том же месте, что и до поворота? Вне зависимости используется ли метод setRetainInstance или нет. Фрагмент же полностью уничтожается (если не использовать setRetainInstance). Пример: проскроллил список до конца, переворачиваю - я по прежнему нахожусь в конце списка. RecyclerView сохраняет состояние?

Comment: Все `view` у которых есть `id` сохраняют своё состояние автоматически.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если открыть исходники Recycler view то можно увидеть метод

```
    @Override
protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    SavedState state = new SavedState(super.onSaveInstanceState());
    if (mPendingSavedState != null) {
        state.copyFrom(mPendingSavedState);
    } else if (mLayout != null) {
        state.mLayoutState = mLayout.onSaveInstanceState();
    } else {
        state.mLayoutState = null;
    }

    return state;
}
```

этот метод переопределяется у класса View, когда нужно сохранить состояние вьюхи. В данном случае сохраняется стейт лэйаут менеджера

```
        state.mLayoutState = mLayout.onSaveInstanceState();
```

который содержит как раз состояние скролла.

при этом эти методы отрабатывают, только если у вью  [есть уникальный ID](http://trickyandroid.com/saving-android-view-state-correctly/)